# Can't assign jquery value to session variable in Yii

Tags: php, jquery, session, yii

In the following code the value `item.rmid` is provided by jQuery. The value is fetched from database, displayed in `item.rmid` and has to be stored in `Yii::app()->SESSION["rid"]` but it's not working.

In view I have the following code:

```
$("#pct").html('');
        $.each(<?php echo $ar; ?>, function (i, item) {

            $("#pct").append('
<div class="title">
    fss"
    <?php Yii::app()->SESSION["rid"]=' + item.rmid + ' ; ?>"
    <?php echo Yii::app()->SESSION["rid"];?>
</div>')
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

UPD
 when i var_dump($ar);
following is what i get

```
string '[{"pimg":"12.jpg","pid":"3","createdate":"2014-01-15 12:12:47","rid":"25"},{"pimg":"WP9.JPG","pid":"1","createdate":"2014-01-15 12:14:23","rid":"26"},{"pimg":"n2.jpg","pid":"4","createdate":"2014-01-16 11:01:27","rid":"54"}]
```

but the am unable to assign the rid value ......... know i got it i have multiple rid and am assign it to one Yii::app()->SESSION["rid"] which cant store all value at each iteration...
how do i pass it in the querystring but the valueto be hidden

Comment: Where is a javascript code?

Comment: without session am able to display the value .but i wanna assign it to session variable thats the only thing i need ... have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You can't update stuff on the server via javascript without **AJAX**.
Use ajax to send a request to the server and update the session value using

```
 Yii::app()->session['var'] = $_POST['received_value'];
```

Read up about ajax [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: without session am able to display the value .but i wanna assign it to session variable thats the only thing i need ... have updated the question

Comment: my answer addresses the issue you have, you need to use ajax to updated the session.

Comment: item.rmid is not a post value am fetching it from db ......... what are u trying to say can you please post some sample

Comment: What I am trying to say is that you can't make server side assignments directly using javascript unless you make an http call to the server.

Comment: i have all the values in $ar the only thing i need is to stored that particular rmid in session i can use the get variable as this value is not to be shown to the user

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to note is that PHP part of the code is already finished working when your browser runs your javascript. What your code doing is just assigning the string `' + item.rmid + '` to some PHP variable. It's just a constant string which is not connected to your javascript at all. After that your browser gets something like the following javascript:

```
$("#pct").html('');
$.each(some_array_from_php, function (i, item) {
    $("#pct").append('
        <div class="title">
            fss""
             + item.rmid + 
        </div>')
}
```

Notice how it gets "preprocessed" by PHP. It's not even good javascript really, because you can't use multiline string literals in javascript.

What you can do is to push some value from javascript to your server. So you need to feed javascript code to your browser first, get your value available in javascript and then somehow make another HTTP request passing the value as a GET parameter or something. There is a technology for this purpose, it's called [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). Check this out.

But from your code example it looks like you already have all the values on the server (in `$ar` variable, in JSON format), so you can just assign session variable on PHP and use javascript only for client-side visualization.

First you need to decode JSON:

```
$decoded = json_decode($ar);
```

Now $decoded is just an array of PHP objects, so you can do something like:

```
Yii::app()->session["rid"] = $decoded[0]->rid;
```

Above we are storing the "rid" of the first object to session. If you want to store all of them just loop through `$encoded` while pushing values to session like this:

```
foreach ($decoded as $obj) {
    Yii::app()->session["rids"][] = $obj->rid;
}
```

Comment: exactly i have all the values in $ar the only thing i need is to stored that particular rmid in session ....

Comment: via Yii::app()->session["rid"] = $ar[0]["rmid"]; am still unable to assign the value

Comment: @tisha what does it mean that you are "unable to assign"? Does it throw some error? Try `var_dump` to precisely determine the value stored in session after this call. Update your question with new code (but don't throw away your original question, just add UPD section)

Comment: i have updated my question and found that i cant assign it Yii::app()->session["rid"] as $ar has multiple value  do we have something like  pass each rid it in the querystring but the value to be hidden

Comment: Looks like `$ar` contains json-encoded string (where did you get this?). To use it in PHP you need to `json_decode` it to PHP structure, find what you want using PHP and assign it.

Comment: @tisha Did you my suggestion? Maybe I need to clarify something a bit?

Comment: i did gave it a try but it dint work :(. ya please go ahead to clarify :)

Comment: @tisha what exactly are going wrong? Got any errors? Check my edited answer.

Comment: thanks  for the clarification :) .... have know understood l give it a try ... for know i have changed much to my code ..as of know am working on some other part.. l let u know if their are any errors ... ..... i hope you dont mind